# Apache can't run after upgrade PHP

Tags: php

- I upgraded the PHP from 7.2.9 to 7.4.11.
- I can't start the Apache server the error is "The Apache shutdown unexpectedly.".
- it is not the problem with the port I changed it already.
- in the Apache error log, I got this warning " PHP Warning:
  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0 ".
- after this, I installed the VC_redist 2019 also but the error is the same.
- also, PHP -v command output is PHP 7.4.11 (CLI) (built: Sep 29 2020
  13:19:25) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x86 .

I am using Xampp server.
please help me, thanks

Comment: I think you either will have to upgrade Apache or downgrade PHP

Comment: Download the latest Microsoft Visual C++ package

Comment: I already downloaded and install that @Phil795

Comment: Which version of Xampp are you using?

Comment: version 3.2.2 @NaserNikzad

Comment: Uninstall xampp and install a new version with PHP 7.4

Comment: What version of vc_redist do you have installed? With me it works with 14.23.2780 and Xampp 3.2.4 with PHP 7.4.9 without problems